# How can I update the launch template version to be set to latest in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, launch-template

I am trying to set the the latest version to default in the launch template using Terraform.
You can do this quite easily in the AWS console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePSeq.png)

But I can't seem to find in TF documentation a way to do so.

I am using AWS provider 4.14 in TF.

There is an option to set the latest version but it expects an integer https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.14.0/docs/resources/launch_template#latest_version

I would like to set that whenever there is an update to the launch template a new version will be created and set to default.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That is an attribute, not an argument. You can't set that, because it's an output of a successful apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [update_default_version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/launch_template#update_default_version):

> Whether to update Default Version each update. Conflicts with default_version

Answer (score 1):

You can use update_default_version=true parameter inside resource block, which will make terraform to set latest version as default one.

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/4.14.0/docs/resources/launch_template#update_default_version

here is the doc about that parameter